# Is there any version of Jensen's inequality for quasiconvex function

Tags: calculus, probability, inequality, convex-analysis

I am looking for some generalization of Jensen's inequality for functions $g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $g(x)$ is quasiconvex (or not convex). We known that for convex functions,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[g(x)\right] \ge g\left(\mathbb{E}[x]\right).$$ Is there a generalization  of this result for quasiconvex functions or functions which are not convex.

Thanks

Comment: What's your definition of quasi-convex?

Comment: If by quasiconvex you mean $\forall t \in (0, 1), \quad f\left(t a+ (1-t)b\right) \le \max \left(f(a), f(b)\right)$ then there is the Jensen like inequality $f(\sum_i w_i x_i) \le \max_i f(x_i)$ where $w_i $ are weights that sum to $1$, and $a \le x_i \le b$.